# I try to make my website secure using AWS CloudFront, but I cannot change Bucket policy of S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, web

In order to make my website secure (when I visit my website, it says "unsecure" in the top left corner), I did the following.

1. create ACM certification and verify using Route 53
2. create Cloudfront with this certification
3. Create original access in Cloudfront
4. Give permission to my S3 to be accessed by CloudFront by changing bucket policy.

Step 4 doesn't work with the following error

```
Unknown Error
An unexpected error occurred.
API response
Invalid principal in policy
```

My bucket policy looked like this.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity E3BVR0DQ0EMFFZ"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::songms.com/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I go to my website I get

```
403 ERROR
The request could not be satisfied.
Bad request. We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.
If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.

Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
Request ID: vmlx8bao1D8k0myKHiGBSBCnCZDcZIUBiwNS1kIMEF_99Y_Gs0ZWQQ==
```

What did I do wrong?

I have toyed with this for several hours without any progress.
All I want is to make my website "secure" and I heard that to do so I need to use cloudfront and ACM.. Please, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se] and questions about managing your server should be asked on [sf]. Please delete your question here and re-ask it in one of those two more appropriate places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should post your config here so people can better understand where you are missing.
However, I think you haven't attached the OAI to Origin
With the error of not being able to change your s3 policy, I think your user does not have the permission to do that. You can edit s3 policy yourself instead of letting cloudfront do it. If that doesn't work, ask someone else with higher permission.